# Spring 3 MVC -- The requested resource is not available

Tags: spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

My Spring JSP is not coming up when I call it.  Apparently the resource is not available.  Here is my controller code.

```
@Controller
public class BulletinsController {
    private List<Bulletin> bulletins;
    private BulletinDAO bulletinDAO;

    // getters and setters, including autowiring for the BulletinDAO

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getApprovedBulletins", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView getApprovedBulletins() {
        try {
            bulletins = bulletinDAO.getApprovedBulletins();
            mav.setViewName("WEB-INF/jsp/EnterBulletin");
            if (bulletins != null) {
                mav.addObject("bulletins", bulletins);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            mav.setViewName("WEB-INF/jsp/FailurePage");
        }

        return mav;
    }
```

Here is the relevant part of jcbulboard-servlet.xml

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/cpc" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="bulletinDAO" class="com.dao.BulletinDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="bulletinsController" class="com.controller.BulletinsController">
        <property name="bulletinDAO" ref="bulletinDAO" />
    </bean>
```

Here is my web.xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
        <display-name>Job Connections Bulletin Board</display-name>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>jcbulboard</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>jcbulboard</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>Welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: If its a HTTP 404, it usually means the path to your JSP is wrong in your controller.  Looking at what you have, you usually don't specify the WEB-INF part, and most of the times the jsp part as well.

Comment: I removed "WEB-INF/jsp/", but I still got the same error message.

Comment: Do you have a org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver in your Spring config? If so, what are the prefix and suffix properties config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a view resolver to your `jcbulboard-servlet.xml`:

```
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

Instead of

```
mav.setViewName("WEB-INF/jsp/FailurePage");
```

It would be

```
mav.setViewName("FailurePage");
```

Assuming there is a file named:

```
WEB-INF/jsp/FailurePage.jsp
```